# Having Class object inside the Class ctor

Tags: c++

How to properly use a class object (Point) inside my class (Segment) object that they both inheritoring from the class(Figure2D)?

The Figure.h file:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <ostream>
class Figure2D
{
private:
    double x;
    double y;
    double length;
    double height;
    char* name = NULL;
public:
    Figure2D(double l, double h, double x = 0, double y = 0);
    Figure2D(Figure2D& f);
    Figure2D();
    virtual ~Figure2D();
    const Figure2D& operator=(Figure2D& d);
    void setName(const char*);
    double getX()const;
    double getY()const;
    double getLength()const;
    double getHeight()const;
    const char* getName()const;
    double Area()const;
    double Perimeter()const;
    void Shift(double dx, double dy);
    void MoveTo(double newX, double newY);
    void Resize(double newL, double newH);
    void Scale(double Kx, double Ky);
    bool isInside(Figure2D* P);//Point(P->getX(),P->getT()) lies inside the figure
    void print()const;
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& o, Figure2D& d);
};
```

The Point.h file:

```
#pragma once
#include "Figure2D.h"
class Point : public Figure2D {
public:
    Point(const char* s,int x,int y) :Figure2D(0,0,x,y)
    {
        setName(s);
    }
    Point(){}
    Point(const Point& other)
    {
    }
    ~Point() {}
};
```

The Segment.h file:

```
    #pragma once
#include "Figure2D.h"
#include "Point.h"
class Segment : public Figure2D
{
public:
    Segment(const char* s, Point& p1, Point& p2)
    {
        setName(s);
        if (p1.getX() <= p2.getX() && p1.getY() <= p2.getY())
        {
            isLeftToRightSegment = true;
        }
        else
        {
            isLeftToRightSegment = false;
        }
    }
protected:
    bool isLeftToRightSegment;
};
```

I cant make this code in the main.cpp properly:

```
Segment S("Segment PQ", P, Q);
```

Eventually i want to make shaps as(Point,Segment,Rectangle,Square,Circle) with the
Figure2D class

Comment: It isn't clear what your problem is. Are there any compilation errors or erroneous output? Please show. Besides, you have a very large base class without a single virtual function (apart from the destructor). This is rather dubious.

Comment: There are more than one issue to note. But let's just take the usage of the `setName()` function in the body of the `Segment`'s constructor. The  `name` lives in the scope of the parent `Figure2D` class. So, it should be initialized appropriately, say, like so:  `Segment(name = "foo") : Figure2D(name) {}`. You may want to check this [article](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor).

Comment: Please be more specific than "I can't make this [...] properly". What exactly happens, or doesn't happen, when you try?

Comment: when i run the code the S object dosent get nothing inside him

Comment: You aren't storing `p1` and `p2` anywhere in your `Segment` class. You probably forgot to forward something to the base `Figure2D` constructor.